# Proof that the rank of two component vectors product of any matrix is always 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$ be a square matrix, and define:
$u = A_{ij}$ where $i=1,\ldots,(n-1), j=n$
$v^T = A_{ij}$ where $i = n, j = 1,\ldots,(n-1)$.

In simpler words, $u$ is the vector that contains the last column of $A$, without the element $A_{nn}$,
and $v^T$ is the vector that contains the last line of $A$, without the element $A_{nn}$.

Given the product $B = uv^T$, prove that $\operatorname{rank}(B) = 1, (\forall) \ A \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$.

This means that it exists at least 1 element $u_iv_j$ of $B$ such that $u_iv_j \neq 0$ and all determinants from order $2$, up to $n-1$ are $0$.

Is the determinant approach a good start or should I look into some other properties (of a matrix rank)?
Thank you!

Comment: So, the matrix doesn't tell you anything; all we need to know is that $u,v$ are arbitrary vectors.

Comment: Compute the matrix product, and note that all rows (or columns) of the result are multiples of each other.